# TCP/IP basics, offset, reassembly

Tags: ethernet, tcp, pcap.net

I`m writing packet generator right now. Testing it with wireshark and VM. I have an exercise on my checklist to sent 3 packets in a row:
1. TCP on 80 port, with SYN=1 and MF=1 flags.
2. TCP on 135 port, with SYN=1 and MF=1 flags. 
3. TCP on 80 port, with MF = 0 and offset = 24.

I`m sending all the packets with the same ID field on IP layer.So as I understand Wireshark should try to reassemble these packets.
But will it reassemble packets from different ports?And what should we get as final result?
All I get is 3 IPv4 packets.

http://cs625124.vk.me/v625124860/10bf5/BQFUbKT7zVs.jpg

**Addition**: I mentioned, that if I change offset of last TCP-packet to 16, than we got a bit different kind of traffic.:

We got one HTTP or continuos packet. And here is wrong checksum. I tried to copy correct checksum to the first TCP packet and then I got RST, so i think that WireShark interpreted SYN from 1-st packet:
http://s28.postimg.org/z3w7ibhjx/image.png

So could you please explain me, was the last result correct? I would appreciate any help. Sorry if it is something basic. It`s my first expirience of writing WinForm application and using Pcap.Net library too. Thanks in advance!Sorry for links, have no reputation(

Answer (score 0):

First, a TCP session is defined by the tuple:

1. Side A's IP address.
2. Side A's Port.
3. Side B's IP address.
4. Side B's Port.

If you have packets with different tuples, they will not be part of the same TCP session.

You get a RST when the server closes the session.

It is likely the server doesn't like getting SYN packets from port 21 (FTP) to its port 80 (HTTP).